# IntelliJ reports "sources not found" even though source opened in other module

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module, ide

I have

```
ScanResults results; // me.unroll.scanner.ScanResults

logFilterStateReceived(filterState, results.googleImage);
```

I just added the field `googleImage`. It's giving me the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'googleImage". When I jump to the declaration of `ScanResults` it fails to retrieve the source and recompiles something - *something*, I don't know what - into an obsolete version of my Scanner module.

So

- the Scanner module is open
- in Project Structure > Email-Lib, where the above code sample lives, Scanner is listed as a compile dependency with the little folder icon, which I think means it's working / on disc
- I redeployed the code to Maven in any case.

Why is it not pulling the local code?

Answer (score 0):

I had `Scanner` listed as a dependency twice. One was as a module and one was as a Maven jar. What probably happened is I loaded the higher library before the I added the lower one as a module, although I'm not sure why it preferred the module dependency (besides it being higher in the list). Removing the library dependency fixed it, although I would expect my build to break if I close the module. This is something Eclipse seemed better at handling automatically (prefer open project, fallback to Maven repo).